# Call didReceiveRemoteNotifacation when app is force-quit

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

Will the  'didReceiveRemoteNotifacation' method gets called, if I use PushKit framework, when the app is force-quit by the user ?

Comment: Why not use a 'silent push'?

Comment: It doen't call the didReceiveNotification: Method, when my app is forceQuit.

Comment: Yes, there is nothing you can do to receive a notification in that case